# Why am I mutating the original array with filter method? [React]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

After executing the `newData[0].id = newValue` I am actually updating the react **initialData** state. **How is that possible?**

Is my understanding that filter should return a new array different than the original one, also I am not ussing the **setState** feature so I don't understand why the state is changing.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74686072/edit) it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because arrays are mutable. it will keep the reference to the original array even after filtering.

use the spread operator to avoid mutating the original array

```
const data = [...newData]
data[0].id = newValue
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the new beta docs on [updating items in array](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#updating-objects-inside-arrays)

```
setInitialData(prev => {
 // create a new array
 const withReplaced = prev.map(elem => {

    if (elem.id === id) {
        const newVal = //set new value
        // create a new updated element
        return {
          ...elem,
          id: newVal
        }
      } else {
        // The rest haven't changed
        return elem;
      }

  });

 return  withReplaced;

})
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you can't update the initialData,but the you can update the son of the array.And if you don't use "setData".The views won't change.